# How to copy linpus Linux drivers and add/replace in ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, battery, acer

I bought acer laptop with linpus Linux. Everything works in linpus smoothly but in Ubuntu i am facing several problems like : Touchpad not working, wireless devices not working, poor battery life etc. How can i fix them?
Edit:- Laptop model -Acer E5-574G-50XN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can simply copy the drivers, maybe someone else who has tried it can answer that.

Not knowing your laptop's model I can't say for sure, but I had similar issues as you on my Acer VN7 792G. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 and was able to fix wireless and touchpad:

- as for the touchpad, install kernel 4.5. I'm currently using 4.5rc5 and it's working fine. [Howto update kernel](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/02/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-5-rc5-in-linux.html) (official Canonical build):
- as for the wifi, it's a known bug for my model and there is a firmware available, which together with kernel 4.5 works ok :) [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520343), [fix instructions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1520343/comments/22)

Comment: And how can i improve battery life?

Comment: I've stumbled upon someone else reporting poor battery life here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1546129
But for me, it was ok. I've tested it yesterday and I got more than 3 hours of normal usage (downloading big file, installing packages, etc. with high screen brightness). Maybe the newer kernel fixes it as well? No idea, I haven't tried it on 4.2.